# How to inform the user on POST fails in Dialogflow's promises?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

In my dialogflow agent, in fulfillment, I have a part in my code where I call a promise and the bot responds to the user with some data from a server. In case of success, everything works as intended. However, in case of an error (e.g. sever down) I want to print a message to the user stating that an error occurred and he/she doesn't need to wait for an answer for the eternity.

```
      return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        const request = require('request-promise-native');
        const options = {  
          uri: 'https://server.server.com/example',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'api-token': 'code'
        },
          body: {
            user:'user_name'
         },
        json: true
    };

    request(options)
        .then(function (body) {
            // POST succeeded
            console.log("got: "+ body);
            agent.add("SUCCESS");
            resolve();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // POST failed...
            console.log("ERROR!: " + err);            
            agent.add("I am sorry for the inconvenience but an error happened during your last call.");
            agent.add("Please try in a while");
            console.log(err.stack);
        });
    });
```

The error messages after a failed POST message are printed in the log files (so it gets in the .catch section) but the user doesn't get any messages, the agent.add() function doesn't work in that case, which seems strange. How can I print a message to the user when the promise procedure has failed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do that in then, according to response of post request. For example, build a promise function and reject error when error occurs. Then in your intent handler, get rejected answer and display your error message if there is reject response from function.

I'm not familiar with 'request-promise-native' but you can try this with 'request' module in your promise

```
request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
   if (error) {
     console.log(error);
     reject(error);
   }
   else {
     answer = body;
     resolve(answer);
   }
});
```

and then in your intent handler

```
promisefunction()
.then((resolve, reject) => {
if (reject)
{
 agent.add("I am sorry for the inconvenience but an error happened during your last call.");
 agent.add("Please try in a while");
}
else
agent.add("SUCCESS");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-catch statement? I don't know what error occurs but if you receive an error, surely you can catch it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The server is down in my case and the request(options).catch is catching the error (it prints in the logs about the error, a line below "POST failed" comment), but the agent.add() function below doesn't seem to have any response. The final line with the log again is working.

Comment: What is the "agent.add()" doing?

Comment: It prints the response of the chatbot. agent.add("Hello!"); prints "Hello!". The console.log() prints in the logs.